# bash replace string with floating variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed, floating

Im trying to replace a number in a file with a calculated floating variable in a bash file. So im trying to replace 1.1111 with the value of "km" and save it in the mesh.in file. I keep getting an error on the sed line, I think there may be an issue with the floating variable. Echo "$km" does work so i know that the km is not the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Angle in degrees : " n1
read -p "bcsa : " n2
cd viv_example_se2d
sed s/^bcsa.\*/"bcsa $n2"/ runfile.viv >temp
mv -f temp runfile.viv
cd ../
for i in $(seq 2 0.5 12)
do
    if  [ ! -d U*_$i ];then
        mkdir U*_$i
    fi
    printf -v "km" "%.4f\n" $(echo | bc | awk "BEGIN {print 4*3.14159265359*3.14159265359/($i*$i)}")
    echo "$km"
    cd viv_example_se2d
    sed s/1.1111/$km/g mesh_master.in > temp$i 

    mv -f temp$i mesh.in
    cd ../
    echo $home/lustre/projects/p057_swin/ogoldman/Ellipse_$n1/U*_$i | xargs -n 1 cp viv_example_se2d/*
done;
```

Comment: That `echo | bc |` bit of that command is doing absolutely nothing and can be dropped.

Comment: What error are you getting from `sed`?

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command

Comment: And what is the value of `$km` exactly? Oh! Drop the `\n` from your `printf` format. You don't want the value of `$km` to contain a newline.

Comment: Show sample input and expected output as we can't tell from a non-working script what it is you are trying to do but we CAN tell it's the wrong way to do it (since it's the wrong way to do anything).

Comment: The problem is the newline in the value of `$km`. That being said EdMorton is exactly correct in that this script is (as I indicated in my comment and my answer) a big mess.

Comment: inputs would be degrees anything between 0 and 90 and bcsa would be something like 0.52360 or 0.72305 its a function of the degrees that varies and is calculated elsewhere

Comment: output of $km should be x.xxxx where x can be any number

Comment: Just drop the `\n`. Perfect. Thanks a heap

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the newline in the value of `$km`. It is confusing `sed`.

That being said this script is also a bit of a mess.

You should quote your variables when you use them to protect against problems with whitespace and glob characters in the values.

You don't need `xargs` to `cp` multiple files that you can expand via a glob. `cp` will happily take multiple files to copy directly. (Oh, or is that copying multiple files to directories produced via that glob?)

You have a useless `echo | bc |` bit near the `awk` command.

Using full/relative paths in `sed`/etc. is better than `cd`ing around generally.

Comment: Didnt mean to have the `-i ` and `| bc - l `. I was playing around trying a few different things and couldnt fix it. Script has been editted. Also dont worry about the `$..../U*_$i` it had a long path so i just removed the beginning which isnt important

Comment: You need to show us **exactly** the code you are working with and **exactly** the problem you are having or we can't help you correctly.